# Quartz 2.2.1 : Failure obtaining db row lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am getting below exception when is deployed quartz to UAT environment. All tables are present in correct schema. Still having below issue. Can anyone suggest reason behind this.

> ERROR>
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager[main]:
>   ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure obtaining db row lock:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3258)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3858)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:3843)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:687)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet.init(QuartzInitializerServlet.java:211)
```

Comment: Does the user that accesses the Database have the appropriate privileges on the table in question? Run this and paste the result here: `SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS where upper(grantee) = upper('CLUSTER_MANAGER_USER');`.

Comment: It does not return an result from my UAT and DEV both the DB's. But quartz is working in DEV.

Comment: Don't use `CLUSTER_MANAGER_USER` - it was just an example. Replace it with the user that actually connects to the Database.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but after correcting select query, still it does not return anything from both DEV and UAT

Comment: This just means, that you got the user wrong. You see, this process must connect to the Database, or execute other processes that do that. They surely use a specific user to do so - that's the one that you need.

Comment: but it has same access as DEV

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to compare the two schemas (between DEV and UAT) to get the differences. In case the user's the same and it has the same privileges, then it really must be a missing table; since you can't determine which one is it, then compare the schemas and find out. The simplest is just to count the tables like so: `select * from all_tables where uppeR(owner) = UPPER('OWNER_SCHEMA');` - execute this on both the environments. Keep in mind, that DEV and UAT might differ by default to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for your time @g00dy . It was different mistake. Actually i was using one of the older framework jar(Not quartz). That was not able to set schema correctly. Issue resolved after i replaced jar.